# Checking emails exist , auto-reconnect tcpclient c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to create a app checking email exist using .NET

I was thinking for 2 hours didn't figure any solution

the purpose of this solution is make my server dodging the ban or exceed of test.

**my problem is how to auto-reconnect the `TcpClient` after number of email checked and continuing from last email in the Array**

```
public void isChecked(string[] MailCheck,string length)
{
    //converte ArrayLength from string to int
    int num = int.Parse(length);


    TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("smtp-in.orange.fr", 25);
    string CRLF = "\r\n";
    byte[] dataBuffer;
    string ResponseString;
    NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
    ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
    /* Perform HELO to SMTP Server and get Response */
    dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO Contact" + CRLF);
    netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
    dataBuffer = BytesFromString("mail from:<contact@contact.com>" + CRLF);
    netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {


    /* Read Response of the RCPT TO Message to know from google if it exist or not */

    dataBuffer = BytesFromString("rcpt to:<" + MailCheck[i] + ">" + CRLF);
    netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
    if (GetResponseCode(ResponseString) == 550)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("false " + ResponseString);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("false   || " + ResponseString);
    }
    else
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("true " + ResponseString);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("true    || " + ResponseString);

        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:/WarningsLog.txt", MailCheck[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

- put the recipients into a List
- as outer loop, iterate while the list is not empty. To avoid an endless loop, you may consider to limit the number of iterations.
- connect to the SMPT server
- as inner loop, send the messages. When a mail could be sent, remove the recipient from the list. If a transient error occured, exit the inner loop

Did you consider using an existing SMTP client implementation like https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit or at least System.Net.SmtpClient?